# Sorting log file into groups with bash and awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I'm trying to sort a log file in a specific way, but I'm not sure how to perform the last step.

My logfile has entries like this:

```
Feb 15 17:00:34 server sshd[13879]: Invalid user test from 200.242.94.133
Feb 15 17:00:35 server sshd[13780]: Invalid user ftpuser from 200.242.94.133
Feb 15 17:01:34 server sshd[13890]: Invalid user test from 200.242.94.133
Feb 15 17:01:35 server sshd[13791]: Invalid user vnc from 200.242.94.133
Feb 15 17:01:35 server sshd[13794]: Invalid user test from 50.63.172.108
Feb 15 17:01:36 server sshd[13798]: Invalid user vnc from 50.63.172.108
```

I use the command:

```
cat logfile | grep "Invalid user" | awk '{print $8 ", " $10 }' | sort -t":" -k2,2 | uniq -c
```

Which outputs:

```
 1 ftpuser, 200.242.94.133
 2 test, 200.242.94.133
 1 test, 50.63.172.108 
 1 vnc, 200.242.94.133
 1 vnc, 50.63.172.108
```

I'd like to get:

```
1 ftpuser, (1) 200.242.94.133
3 test, (2) 200.242.94.133, (1) 50.63.172.108
2 vnc, (1) 200.242.94.133, (1) 50.63.172.108
```

I'm not sure how to sum the words column while keeping the ip address counted separate and then including it with other results.

Attempt with answer:

```
# awk '/Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}' logfile | sort -k2
awk: /Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}
awk:                                 ^ syntax error
awk: /Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}
awk:                                                                                                   ^ syntax error
awk: /Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}
awk:                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}' logfile
2 vnc, (1) 50.63.172.108, (1) 200.242.94.133
1 ftpuser, (1) 200.242.94.133
3 test, (1) 50.63.172.108, (2) 200.242.94.133
```

If you want it sorted alphabetically by user:

```
$ awk '/Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++} END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}' logfile | sort -k2
1 ftpuser, (1) 200.242.94.133
3 test, (1) 50.63.172.108, (2) 200.242.94.133
2 vnc, (1) 50.63.172.108, (1) 200.242.94.133
```

The above works with GNU `awk`.  I haven't tested with BSD.

#### How it works

- `/Invalid user/{user[$8]++;ip[$8][$10]++}`

  For any line in `logfile` with an invalid user, this counts up the user name, field 8, and the ip address, field 10.
- `END{for (u in user){printf "%s %s",user[u],u;for (i in ip[u])printf ", (%s) %s",ip[u][i],i;print""}}`

  When we have finished reading `logfile`, this loops through every user that we have seen and prints the number of times that we have seen that user, followed by that user's name, followed by, for each ip address, a count for that ip followed by that ip.

Comment: Kudos for elegance and concision. Requires GNU `awk`; will not work with BSD awk or mawk (lack of true multi-dimensional arrays). A caveat is that the order of IP addresses will be seemingly random due to unsorted enumeration of the associative array. On gawk 4.0+, to get at least alphabetical sorting, you can add `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` as the 1st statement in the `END` block - this also makes the  `sort` command unnecessary. As for the `sort` command: better to use  `sort -k2,2` (`sort -k2` unnecessarily compares the name field  _plus the remainder of the line_).

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to come up with this - I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and seem to get a `syntax error`, showing for this part `ip[u][i],`

Comment: @JoeHabadas With that version of `awk`, it should work.  I just copied-and-pasted from the answer and ran the code again and it still works for me.   With `awk`, you can get a syntax error if there is merely a space in the wrong place.  For example, inserting a space like `ip[u] [i]` would generate a syntax error.  Would you try again and, if it fails again, copy-and-paste the code and error message in their entirety into your question?  Just put it an the end of the question.  (Don't try pasting it into a comment: when pasting more than one line, comments destroy formatting.)

Comment: @John1024, Hi John, I've posted the result in my answer as requested.

Comment: @JoeHabadas: It is your _awk_ version that matters, not that of _bash_; while your bash version suggests that you're on Fedora or Red Hat Linux, where GNU awk is the default awk, your error message suggests that your awk is _not_ GNU awk. Try `awk --version` to see what it is. If it's acceptable, try running your command with `gawk` instead of `awk`; if not, use my POSIX-compliant solution.

Comment: @mklement0, ah, sorry about that - it's `GNU Awk 3.1.7` - so I should upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: @JoeHabadas: Yes, upgrading to the current version should solve the problem.

Comment: @mklement0, The upgrade to `GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1` did the trick. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28598575/45375) is a very concise and presumably fast solution that is an option, IF:

- you're using *GNU* awk (the solution uses non-POSIX features that won't work with BSD awk (also used on OS X) or mawk, for instance).
- you don't mind a seemingly random order of IP addresses (due to unsorted key enumeration of an associative array; however, in GNU awk 4.0+, you can use [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to control the enumeration order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)).

Here is a much more pedestrian solution, which, however:

- uses only POSIX awk features.
- lists IP addresses in the order encountered in the input.

It builds on a slightly simplified version of the OP's command.

```
awk '/Invalid user/ { print $8 ", " $10 }' logfile | sort -t":" -k2,2 | uniq -c |
awk '
    # Helper output function for printing an output line.
  function printLine(c, n, l) { 
    sub(/,$/, "", n); print c, n l
  }
    # End of previous block found (new username)?
  prevName != $2 {
      # Print summary line for previous block.
    if (NR>1) printLine(count, prevName, ipList)
      # Start new block.
    prevName=$2; count=0; ipList=""
  }
    # Build block summary values.
  { 
    count+=$1
    ipList=ipList ", (" $1 ") " $3
  }
    # Print summary line for last block.
  END { 
    printLine(count, prevName, ipList)
  }
  '
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How do I use the helper function? I tried pasting it in after my original attempt, and tried using as a shell script but couldn't seem to get output. Sorry if I sound like a noob, just not sure how it works.

Comment: @JoeHabadas: I'm not entirely sure what you tried, but note that the helper function is part of an _awk_ program, not a _shell_ function: _everything from the 2nd line is a single awk program_, inside a multi-line, single-quoted string, so you need to paste the whole thing.

Comment: It was a tough choice of which answer to pick, but I decided to go with `John1024's`, mostly because of the simplicity - I really do appreciate you taking the time to come up with this though. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure, @JoeHabadas. If GNU awk can be used, John's answer is undoubtedly the better choice.